# NSURL object is nil even after initialization with a string

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a string as follows (*Which actually is a link*) 
`http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/goat/mainMenuNew.png`
(x is replaced by the ip address)

I want to convert it to a URL. Below is what i did,

```
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:objUserInfo.photoLink];
```

also tried `alloc` and `initWithString`.

But, `imageUrl` is nil in both the cases.

Please let me know where am i going wrong.

Comment: Are you sure that objUserInfo.photoLink is not nil?

Comment: Ya it is not nil. I did print it prior passing it as a parameter.

Comment: What @BenTrengrove said. Also, it's worth adding in an NSLog() or something to make sure it's not a malformed URL; if it is, your NSURL object will be nil.

Comment: Another note, not sure if its a typo but you have a space between http: and //xxx. That would also cause a nil URL

Comment: You have a space between http: and //

Comment: Actually the space does not exist. I was not allowed to post my question because of the link , that's the reason i added a space.:)

Comment: Using ARC? Did this go out of scope before you tried to access it? Perhaps a little more code to determine its usage would help :)

Comment: @bgoers Local variables are `strong` by default with ARC.

Comment: @rmaddy Ooh yes I have lost my head. The compiler would also complain if the imageURL was no longer defined in a block. My bad!

Comment: @Raj can you NSLog objUserInfo.photoLink and print the log here. Also, NSLog imageUrl and print the log here.

Comment: The docs for `NSURL` say that `nil` will be returned if the URL string is malformed (whatever that actually means). Make sure the URL is truly properly formed. Post the real, actual URL string to get another pair of eyes looking at it.

Comment: I m not using an ARC. NSLog of objUserInfo.photoLink is as followshttp://172.17.109.130:8080/goat/mainMenuNew.png

Comment: After creating the url log is,url is (null)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try followings:

- Check if `objUserInfo.photoLink` still contains the string, by logging it before converting to URL
- If it does try trimming your string with:

  ```
  [objUserInfo.photoLink stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
  ```
- Check san's answer for adding percent escapes if problem persist

Answer (score 2):

Add this, also your link include space or not.

```
NSString *urlStr =[objUserInfo.photoLink stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *imageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:urlStr];
```

Paste to Safari this link: http://www.google.com/search?q=I%20Love%20You Enter and you'll understand what the code do.

Comment: Ya thank you, its working, but the url is preceded by the following characters %0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20. Is it normal to have it?

Comment: @Raj You must have parsed the URL string from some text and you ended up with leading carriage return and spaces. Use the answer by "rptwsthi" to trim the leading whitespace and newline.

Comment: Yes, %0A, or %20 replace some special character when working with URL.Don't worry about it. I don't remember,maybe %20 = space. Alway do it with internet URL

Comment: @Raj sang say's right %20  need to fill up your URL white-space so you must encoding your URL sting with %20 +1 for good Answer Sang